# Автоматическое ScrollBar в TextBox

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox, scrollbar

Подскажите, пожалуйста, есть ли возможность реализации автоматического появления вертикального scrollbar в textbox в случае если вносимое значение больше по строкам чем textbox.
Т.е. текст меньше площади textbox - scrollbar отсутствует. Больше - появляется. Спасибо!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно как то так:

```
    private void textBox2_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Size sz = TextRenderer.MeasureText(textBox2.Text, textBox2.Font);
        if (sz.Height > textBox2.Height)
            textBox2.ScrollBars = ScrollBars.Vertical;
        else
            textBox2.ScrollBars = ScrollBars.None;
    }
```

с горизонталью аналогично
и не забудьте textBox2.Multiline = True

Answer (score 0):

```
public static Size GetTextDimensions(this TextBox textBox)
{
    Font font = textBox.Font;
    string stringData = textBox.Text;
    int width = textBox.Width;
    using (Graphics g = textBox.CreateGraphics())
    {
        SizeF sizeF = g.MeasureString(stringData, font, width);
        return new Size((int)Math.Ceiling(sizeF.Width), (int)Math.Ceiling(sizeF.Height));
    }
}

textbox.TextChanged += (s, a) =>
{
    Size size = GetTextDimensions(textbox);
    textbox.ScrollBars = size.Height > textbox.Height ? ScrollBars.Vertical : ScrollBars.None;
};
```

Идея взята отсюда:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16424931/how-to-hide-the-vertical-scrollbar-while-the-textbox-is-not-full-and-display-whe/67613513#67613513